# Bounding $L^2$ norm by $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f$ be a real valued function and
$$\|f\|_{\alpha, \beta, \infty} = \|x^\alpha D^\beta f\|_\infty\\ 
\|f\|_{\alpha, \beta, 2} = \|x^\alpha D^\beta f\|_{L^2}$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are multi-indices. I would like to show that
$$\|f\|_2 \leq \|(1+x^2)^{-1}\|_2~\|(1+x^2)f\|_\infty \tag{1}$$
and use this result to prove
$$\|f\|_{\alpha, \beta, 2} \leq C\big(\|f\|_{\alpha, \beta, \infty} + \|f\|_{\alpha+2, \beta, \infty}\big) \tag{2}$$
where $C$ is some positive constant.

So far, using $f = f(1+x^2)(1+x^2)^{-1}$, I have tried using Holder's inequality and the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, but in both cases I get extra powers of two, and I cannot figure out how to bound the $L^2$ norm by an $L^\infty$ norm.

Any tips on establishing these inequalities?

Comment: Well $$ \vert f(x) \vert \leq (1+x^2)^{-1} \Vert(1+y^2) f \Vert_\infty$$ and then the desired inequality follows. It might be that you are forgetting that the $L^2$-norm comes with a square root around the integral.

Comment: If $\vert f(x) \vert \leq C \vert g(x)\vert$, then $$ \Vert f \Vert_2 = \left( \int \vert f(x)\vert^2 dx\right)^{1/2} \leq \left( \int C^2 \vert g(x) \vert^2 \right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{C^2} \Vert g \Vert_2 = C \Vert g \Vert_2.  $$ Now use $g(x) = (1+x^2)^{-1}, C = \Vert (1+y^2) f \Vert_\infty.$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you, that was a lot simpler than I had thought. I will use this result to try and prove (2), does (2) follow similarly?

Comment: Yes, it does. Because $(1+x^2)f= f + x^2 f$.

Comment: I mean, set $h=x^\alpha D^\beta f$ and notice that $\Vert f \Vert_{\alpha, \beta, \infty} = \Vert h \Vert_\infty$ and $\Vert f \Vert_{\alpha, \beta, 2} = \Vert h \Vert_2$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you for all your help. If you would like you can post your comments as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

\begin{align*}
\Vert f \Vert_2 &= \Big( \int \vert f(x) \vert^2 dx\Big)^{1/2}
=\Big( \int (1+x^2)^{-2}\vert (1+x^2) f(x) \vert^2 dx\Big)^{1/2} \\
&\leq \Big( \int (1+x^2)^{-2} \Vert (1+y^2) f\Vert_\infty^2 dx\Big)^{1/2}
= \Vert (1+y^2) f\Vert_\infty \Big( \int \vert (1+x^2)^{-1} \vert^2 dx\Big)^{1/2} \\
&=\Vert (1+y^2) f\Vert_\infty \Vert (1+x^2)^{-1} \Vert_2.
\end{align*}
Let's write $h=x^\alpha D^\beta f$, then we have (using the previous computation for $h$, instead of $f$ and changing $y$ back to $x$)
\begin{align*}
\Vert f\Vert_{\alpha,\beta,2} &= \Vert h \Vert_2 
\leq \Vert (1+x^2)^{-1}\Vert_2 \Vert (1+x^2) h\Vert_\infty \\
&\leq  \Vert (1+x^2)^{-1}\Vert_2 (\Vert h\Vert_\infty + \Vert x^2 h\Vert_\infty ) \\
&=\Vert (1+x^2)^{-1}\Vert_2 (\Vert x^\alpha D^\beta f \Vert_\infty + \Vert x^{\alpha +2} D^\beta f \Vert_\infty) \\
&= \Vert (1+x^2)^{-1}\Vert_2 (\Vert f \Vert_{\alpha, \beta, \infty}+ \Vert f \Vert_{\alpha +2, \beta, \infty}).
\end{align*}
Now, if we are integrating over a domain in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $C=\Vert (1+x^2)^{-1}\Vert_2<\infty$ (if we are in higher dimensions, then we also need to be a bit more careful about our indices $\alpha$).

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: @CBBAM You are welcome.